# How to download a jpg from web to project folder in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I would like to ask How can I download .jpg file from web to my  project's folder which I have created "uploads" ?

I'm trying to downlaod youtube thumbnail image to my" uploads" folder.

My controller:

```
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(http://img.youtube.com/vi/RUgd_GDPhYk/1.jpg);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `System.Net.WebClient`, a .NET class which allows you to make requests for resources via HTTP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.100).aspx

Checked example provided.

```
    var client = new System.Net.WebClient();

    var uri = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/RUgd_GDPhYk/1.jpg";

    // Here, we're just using the same filename as the resource we're after.
    // You may wish to change this to include extra stuff because you'll
    // inevitably run into a naming clash - especially with stuff like 1.jpg
    var targetFilename = Path.GetFileName(uri);

    client.DownloadFile(uri, 
       Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), targetFilename));
```